# merge sql rows together from table

Tags: mysql, aggregate

So my last question was marked as duplicate even though the linked answer ([MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)) had nothing to do with what I was asking. That post refers to pivot tables which probably won't work here. Posting again.

I have a mysql table that has the following data.

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-    --------------------+------------+--------------+
| identifier  | sensor_map_id | sensor_log_id | device_post_log_id | sensor_component_id | logged_at  | sensor_level |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-    --------------------+------------+--------------+
| Level       |          1380 |        788551 |             107392 |                2759 | 1463690100 |        38.00 |
| Temperature |          1380 |        788552 |             107392 |                2760 | 1463690100 |       300.60 |
| Level       |          1381 |        788547 |             107392 |                2761 | 1463690100 |        46.00 |
| Temperature |          1381 |        788548 |             107392 |                2762 | 1463690100 |       299.50 |
| Level       |          1382 |        788549 |             107392 |                2763 | 1463690100 |        45.00 |
| Temperature |          1382 |        788550 |             107392 |                2764 | 1463690100 |       299.50 |
| Level       |          1383 |        100381 |              12664 |                2765 | 1454111400 |       153.00 |
| Temperature |          1383 |        100382 |              12664 |                2766 | 1454111400 |       295.20 |
| Level       |          1383 |        788553 |             107392 |                2773 | 1463690100 |        38.00 |
| Temperature |          1383 |        788554 |             107392 |                2774 | 1463690100 |       300.40 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
```

very little thought was put in to the schema for this data, so every second row shares the same data with a different identifier and sensor_level value. I want to make a query that will merge rows sharing a sensor_map_id, then add two additional columns holding the sensor_level data from the two rows called "level" and "temperature" respectively.

Once formatted, the data should instead look something like this with half as many rows but each row has more columns.

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-    --------------------+------------+---------+
| sensor_map_id | sensor_log_id | device_post_log_id | sensor_component_id | logged_at  | level        | temperature
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-    --------------------+------------+--------------+--------
| 1380          |        788551 |             107392 |                2759 | 1463690100 |        38.00 | 300.60
| 1381          |        788547 |             107392 |                2761 | 1463690100 |        46.00 | 299.50
| 1382          |        788549 |             107392 |                2763 | 1463690100 |        45.00 | 299.50
| 1383          |        100381 |              12664 |                2765 | 1454111400 |       153.00 | 295.20
| 1383          |        788553 |             107392 |                2773 | 1463690100 |        38.00 | 300.40
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+
```

I'd imagine this is easy to do but Mysql is not my forte.

Edit: I am not sure why this is marked as duplicate. The other question is asking about pivot tables, this is more complicated.

Comment: This is a basic pivot. It is no more complicated than that.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would do it then?

Comment: In your example data, the same `sensor_map_id` (e.g. 1380) has two `sensor_log_id` (788551 and 788552).  In your desired pivoted table, there is only one column for `sensor_log_id` and your example output picked just one of the value (788551).  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes that is fine. sensor_log_id does not have to be in the results

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `data`, the following
query gets you the three key columns `sensor_map_id`,
`level`, and `tempature`.  You can add the other column 
as needed.  For example, if either one of the `sensor_log_id` 
will do, you can just add `tL.sensor_log_id` or 
`min(tL.sensor_log_id, tT.sensor_log_id)`

```
select
    tL.sensor_map_id 
    , tL.level
    , tT.tempature
from 
    (
        select
            tL.sensor_map_id
            , tL.level
        from data tL
        where identifier='Level'
    ) as tL
    , (
        select
            tT.sensor_map_id
            , tT.tempature 
        from data tT
        where identifier='Tempature'
    ) as tT 
where 
    tL.sensor_map_id = tT.sensor_map_id
```